# Expression must have a class type

Tags: c++

I didn't want this to be my first post but I'm at a loss here. I keep getting this error when trying to compile my program (which is supposed to simply find the area and perimeter of a rectangle.) This is my header file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle
{
public:
   Rectangle(float Lngth=1, float Wdth = 1);

   void setLngth(float Lngth);
   void setWdth(float Wdth);
   float getLngth(float Lngth);
    float getWdth(float Wdth);
    void Perimeter(float lngth, float wdth);
    void Area(float lngth, float wdth);
private:
    float Lngth;
    float Wdth;
};
```

This is my .cpp file.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "RealRectangle.h" // Employee class definition


 Rectangle::Rectangle(float Lngth, float Wdth)
 {
&Rectangle::setLngth;
&Rectangle::setWdth;
 }
 void Rectangle::setLngth(float Lngth)
 {
      if((Wdth > 0.0) && (Wdth < 20.0))
       float wdth = Wdth;
        else
            cout<<"Invalid Width."<<endl;
 }

 float Rectangle::getLngth(float Lngth)
 {
     return Lngth;
 }

void Rectangle::setWdth(float Wdth)
{
     if((Wdth > 0.0) && (Wdth < 20.0))
       float wdth = Wdth;
        else
            cout<<"Invalid Width."<<endl;
}

float Rectangle::getWdth(float Wdth)
{
    return Wdth;
}

void Rectangle::Perimeter(float lngth, float wdth)
    {
        cout<<"The Perimeter is "<<(2*(lngth + wdth));
    }
void Rectangle::Area(float lngth, float wdth)
    {
        cout<<"The Area is "<<(lngth * wdth);
    }
```

And this is where I keep running into an error. The compiler tells me to add an ampersand to create a pointer as I did in the .cpp. But that creates another error on it's own. And so on. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The errors occur in line 10 and 11.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "RealRectangle.h" 


int main()
{
    Rectangle rectangle1();
    Rectangle rectangle2();

    cout<<rectangle1.Perimeter();
    cout<<rectangle2.Area();
}
```

Comment: Please post the exact error message including the line number.

Comment: You should probably get used to not using `using namespace std;` in your files. It can cause namespace pollution.

Answer (score 2):

You've run into what's been dubbed the most vexing parse.

```
Rectangle rectangle1();
Rectangle rectangle2();
```

declares two functions, not two objects. Do

```
Rectangle rectangle1;
Rectangle rectangle2;
```

Additionally you should probably change those `&Rectangle::setLngth` to function calls.

Answer (score 1):

Rectangle::Perimeter() and Rectangle::Area() are of `void` type. They don't return anything. Yet you're trying to use their non-existent return values and pass it to `cout`.

Either modify these two functions so that they'll return a value:

```
float Rectangle::Perimeter(float lngth, float wdth)
{
        return 2 * (lngth + wdth);
}

float Rectangle::Area(float lngth, float wdth)
{
        return lngth * wdth;
}
```

or modify your main() function to simply call the functions, since as you have them now they already print to `cout`:

```
int main()
{
    Rectangle rectangle1;
    Rectangle rectangle2;

    rectangle1.Perimeter();
    rectangle2.Area();
}
```

But you still have a problem; Those two functions currently take length and width arguments and I don't think that's what you want. It appears that what you want is to get the perimeter and area of the rectangle objects. So you should use the class variables to calculate that. So omit the arguments and use your private data members instead:

```
float Rectangle::Perimeter()
{
        return 2 * (Lngth + Wdth);
}

float Rectangle::Area()
{
        return Lngth * Wdth;
}
```

Don't forgot to also update the function signatures in your class declaration in your header file, not just the implementation in the cpp file.

Furthermore, your constructor doesn't delegate the initialization work correctly. Function calls are of the form `function(arguments)`, not `&function`. So you'll need to do:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(float Lngth, float Wdth)
{
    setLngth(Lngth);
    setWdth(Wdth);
}
```

Finally, the declarations of your `Rectangle` objects are being misinterpreted as function prototypes:

```
Rectangle rectangle1();
Rectangle rectangle2();
```

The compiler thinks that `rectangle1` and `rectangle2` are functions that take no arguments and return a Rectangle. You should omit the parentheses:

```
Rectangle rectangle1;
Rectangle rectangle2;
```

And we're still not finished yet (God, how many errors are in this program :-P). Your `setLngth` and `setWdth` functions are not working as intended:

```
void Rectangle::setLngth(float Lngth)
{
    if((Wdth > 0.0) && (Wdth < 20.0))
        float wdth = Wdth;
    else
        cout<<"Invalid Width."<<endl;
}
```

Take a good look at it.  Especially the line that says `float wdth = Wdth;` What your function does, is take a `float` argument named `Lngth`, then checks if `Wdth` (the private variable) is in range, and if it is, declares a new local `float` variable called `wdth` and sets it to the same value as `Wdth`.

The function does not initialize the private variable `Wdth` at all. Same goes for your `setWdth` function. You should fix those too.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 Rectangle::Rectangle(float Lngth, float Wdth)
 {
&Rectangle::setLngth;
&Rectangle::setWdth;
 }
```

should be this:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(float Lngth, float Wdth)
{
    setLngth(Lngth);
    setWdth(Wdth);
}
```

And this:

```
Rectangle rectangle1();
Rectangle rectangle2();
```

should be this:

```
Rectangle rectangle1;
Rectangle rectangle2;
```